# Existence of threshold value of a probability measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $[0, 1]$ interval. Does a threshold value $c \in [0, 1]$ that satisfies
$$
c = s \mu(\{ c \}) + \mu( (c, 1] )
$$
for some $s \in [0, 1]$ always exist? Is there a name for this threshold value $c$?

For example, if
$$
\mu(x) = \begin{cases}
1/3 & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
1/3 & \text{if $x = 1/4$} \\
1/3 & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}, 
$$
then $c = 1/3$.

Comment: If $\mu$ can be expressed as $f d\lambda$ with $d \lambda$ the Lebesgue measure ($f$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$), then yes. In general, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks! I can focus on that case.

Comment: Well, in this case, the equation is just $0=\int_c^1 f d\lambda-c=:g(c)$. $g$ is continuous and $g(0)=1-c\ge 0$, $g(1)=-c\le 0$. By intermediate value theorem, such $c$ exists.

Comment: Thanks! And even if $\mu$ does not have a corresponding PDF, I thought I could find a threshold $c$ by appropriately choosing $s$.